# Unable to install survminer: package was built under R 3.5.3

Tags: r, survival-analysis

I am trying to install survminer library in R but it is giving me warning

```
> install.packages("survminer", dependencies = TRUE)
Installing package into ‘C:/Users/akjain/Documents/R/win-library/3.5’
(as ‘lib’ is unspecified)
Warning in install.packages :
  dependency ‘cmprsk’ is not available
also installing the dependencies ‘mstate’, ‘muhaz’, ‘deSolve’, ‘flexsurv’


  There is a binary version available but the source version is later:
        binary source needs_compilation
deSolve   1.21   1.23              TRUE

  Binaries will be installed
trying URL 'https://cran.rstudio.com/bin/windows/contrib/3.5/mstate_0.2.11.zip'
Content type 'application/zip' length 826177 bytes (806 KB)
downloaded 806 KB
```

And when I load the library I get the error,

```
library("survminer")
Error: package or namespace load failed for ‘survminer’ in loadNamespace(j <- i[[1L]], c(lib.loc, .libPaths()), versionCheck = vI[[j]]):
 there is no package called ‘cmprsk’
In addition: Warning message:
package ‘survminer’ was built under R version 3.5.3
```

I am using R version 3.5.1

Comment: The important message is: **dependency ‘cmprsk’ is not available**. Is it archived? **No**, it requires R>=3.6.0, upgrade your R version.

Comment: Thanks @NelsonGon . I upgraded R and it worked.

Comment: @NelsonGon I'm sure cmprsk was archived so not sure why that was stated otherwise?

Comment: @42- It seems to be available here: https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/cmprsk/index.html although it errors on CRAN.

Comment: @NelsonGon : I'm not seeing any errors. I just installed version 2.2-7 from source and it loads without complaint in R 3.5.2. If it had "errored" during testing it would not have been on CRAN so you continue to make statements that are unclear at best and possibly completely false. You can check the current status of a package at the Package Checks page: https://cran.r-project.org/web/checks/check_summary_by_package.html

Comment: @42- My apologies, perhaps there is a misunderstanding, perhaps the authors incorrectly stated R 3.6.0 dependency. However, this is version 2.2-8 and maybe this is the reason why. My apologies once again if I did make an incorrect statement. The error is on roldrel-osx as can be seen here: https://cran.r-project.org/web/checks/check_results_cmprsk.html